# How and where save uploaded files with ng-flow?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, flow-js

First of all, I use [ng-flow](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow) (html5 file upload extension on angular.js framework)

My files are uploaded, I log the event in console.
But I don't understand where and how to save them.

Here is my html code, upload is called.

```
<div flow-init flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()">   
<div class="drop" flow-drop ng-class="dropClass">
    <span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn>Upload File</span>
    <span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn flow-directory ng-show="$flow.supportDirectory">Upload Folder</span>
    <b>OR</b>
    Drag And Drop your file here
</div>
```

Here is my config

```
app.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
  flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
    target: 'upload.php',
    permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
    maxChunkRetries: 1,
    chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
    simultaneousUploads: 4,
    singleFile: true
  };
  flowFactoryProvider.on('catchAll', function (event) {
    console.log('catchAll', arguments);
  });
  // Can be used with different implementations of Flow.js
  // flowFactoryProvider.factory = fustyFlowFactory;
}]);
```

`upload.php` is called, and `$_GET` is full with data,

```
<script>alert('alert' + array(8) {
  ["flowChunkNumber"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["flowChunkSize"]=>
  string(7) "1048576"
  ["flowCurrentChunkSize"]=>
  string(6) "807855"
  ["flowTotalSize"]=>
  string(6) "807855"
  ["flowIdentifier"]=>
  string(11) "807855-3png"
  ["flowFilename"]=>
  string(5) "3.png"
  ["flowRelativePath"]=>
  string(5) "3.png"
  ["flowTotalChunks"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
)</script>
```

but when I'm here what I have to do to save my files?

I tried to do `move_uploaded_file()` on `flowFilename` and `flowRelativePath` but nothing append.

I'm new in js.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the upload.php example script:

https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/blob/master/samples/Backend%20on%20PHP.md

```
// init the destination file (format <filename.ext>.part<#chunk>
// the file is stored in a temporary directory
$temp_dir = 'temp/'.$_POST['flowIdentifier'];
$dest_file = $temp_dir.'/'.$_POST['flowFilename'].'.part'.$_POST['flowChunkNumber'];
```

Comment: Please is there any java example? I found only the php one in git

Answer (score 2):

After you upload your image with flow.js, a new post request is sent to your server. You need to handle this POST request and manipulate the file afterwards.

If you are using Java + Spring MVC it would looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    log.debug("REST request to handleFileUpload");
    try {
        BufferedOutputStream stream =
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(path + file.getName())));
        stream.write(file.getBytes());
        stream.close();
        log.debug("You successfully uploaded " + file.getName() + "!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent half a day working with ng-flow and wanted to post the solution to this for PHP. It doesn't take advantage of the chunking and resume functionality, I just needed something that would upload without a page refresh.

First, 
flow-init="{target: '/upload', testChunks:false}"
Example

```
<div flow-init="{target: '/upload', testChunks:false}" flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()" flow-file-success="$file.msg = $message">
            <input type="file" flow-btn />
            <span flow-btn>Upload File</span>
</div>
```

Second,

It should now POST a request to "/upload"..... in that request exists a $_FILES array.

one line of code saved the file for me:

```
$result=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'yourfilename');
```

---

If you are looking to control this through your angular controller, you can set the values like so:

```
    $scope.uploader={};
    $scope.upload = function (id) {

        $scope.uploader.flow.opts.testChunks=false;
        $scope.uploader.flow.opts.target='/upload;
        $scope.uploader.flow.upload();
    }
```

and in your html add:

```
<div flow-init flow-name="uploader.flow">
<button flow-btn>Add files</button>
<div>
```

Don

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called **uploads** means where you moved the temp files to here then add the code in php script.

```
$uploads_dir = 'uploads';
$target_file = $uploads_dir .'/'. basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
```